# Ldap PHP / Stronger authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

PHP Version: 5.6.

I would like to ask you for help in the case of LDAP authentication - PHP.

I have got script:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$adServer = "ldaps://###";

$ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$ldaprdn = 'AD' . "\\" . $username;

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
//putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');

$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

if ($bind) {

    @ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
    $msg = "Invalid email address / password";
    echo $msg."</br>".$ldaprdn."</br>";
}
```

The issue is I'm always receiving

> Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required

I'm using in $adServer - ldapS. I also uncommented the line 'openssl' in php.ini. IIS has been restarted, but still this same issue.

I tried also read some articles here but nothing happened.
Just know that the authentication works good, but it need stronger auth.

Should I add any new Certificate to host? Should I try any port? 636?

In case of any questions do not hesitate to write here.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using [ldap_start_tls](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php)?

Comment: Hello, Thank you. I found an issue. I needed to create a file in C disk called ldap.conf. So the topic is to close. Thank you in advance.